# Is there a way to refresh an Excel Web Access Web Part without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, excel-web-access-webpart

This is done through SharePoint Online.

The Excel Web Access Web Part is displaying a named item (a Chart specifically) from the Excel file (hosted in the Documents library). The data displayed in the chart is just from the same Excel file, NOT from any external data sources.

When I update the Excel file, I see that the Chart in the Excel file has updated to reflect the values. However, the one displayed on the page does not update UNLESS I refresh the whole page.

Is there a way to make the web part reflect changes in real-time? Or at least automatically whenever changes are made to the original file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no real time update possible.

You can do a polling mechanism (which might require some good amount of coding) or just use JavaScript to activate the `Refresh All` connection click event.

If you use Fiddler you can capture the AJAX request that gets sent by the `Refresh All` click. Then use that in JavaScript and call it every X seconds. This will refresh only the webpart.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When I manually click the "Refresh All" it doesn't also refresh immediately the web part. Is this due to the previous version being cached or something on the server?